# How can I implement a gesture recognizer in iOS 3

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

How can I implement gesture recognizers for iOS3 devices?

Comment: Do you mean your iPhone 3G or iOS 3.0? If you mean iOS 3.0 you have to write them by yourself, because they are included in iOS 4.0 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleDoubleTap:)];  
singleFingerDTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;  
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTap];  
[singleFingerDTap release];
```

This is available in iOS 3.2 onwards. Unfortunately for iPad.

More info: [Checkout Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer)

**EDIT:**
You probably should go for UITouch methods then in iOS 3 for iPhone.

More info: [Checkout Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITouch)

Comment: In comments above, @Ali says he means iOS3, and since he specifically says iPhone, it's got to be pre-3.2, since that was iPad-only and was the last 3.x release. So no gesture recognizers, sadly. Shame, because they rock.

Comment: @Dan Ray: Right, on iPhone is up to 3.1.3 was it not? i think i missed the 1 in between.

Comment: Sounds about right. Regardless, the first iOS release for the iPhone that supported UIGestureRecognizer was 4.0.