# IOS: UIgestureRecognizer and touchBegan

Tags: ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

In my view I use three methods (touchbegan, touchmoved and touchended), because I color in a view;
my problem is that I want to add in this view a UITapGestureRecognizer with 2 taps;
is it possible? or touchbegan don't allow this gesture?

Comment: It's possible. Just don't forget to call `[super...]` in overriden methods. There might be some additional tweaking needed, depends on exact behaviour you want to achieve.

Comment: I'll write a code but am not able to test it since i'm at a win computer at the moment.

Comment: Sachin's old-school (pre-gesturerecognizers) might work, too.

Comment: ya right this check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219921/how-can-i-implement-a-gesture-recognizer-in-ios-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya its possible

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if([touch tapCount] == 2){
     NSLog("2 taps");
}
}
```

May this will help u

Comment: but this numbero of tap is a sequence? ( tap-tap) or two finger together?

Comment: its tap-tap, u want two finger together?

Answer (score -1):

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [doubleTap release];


-(void)tapDetected{
    NSLog(@"Double Tap");

}
```